# How to write update in theano function

Tags: python, theano

I am new to theano so maybe this is a simple question.
If I have a function

```
f = theano.function(
          inputs=[x],
          outputs=[y],
          updates=update)
```

and y depends on w that I want to update using

```
w = w + tr_rate * (pos_associations-neg_associations)
```

I can write

```
wparameters = [w]
update = [(wparam, 
           wparam + tr_rate * (pos_associations-neg_associations)) for wparam in wparameters]
```

and it will update the function f using the update rule.

But if y depends on another variable, say z, that I want to update using a different rule, say

```
z = z + tr_rate*(x - vis)
```

How do I combine the two rules together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer and I am posting it if it can help other people.
You can create a variable update and then use the .append function to define new rules.

So, instead of

```
wparameters = [w]
update = [(wparam, 
           wparam + tr_rate * (pos_associations-neg_associations)) for wparam in wparameters]
```

you can append a new rule and write:

```
wparameters  = [w]
zparameters = [z]


update = []
for wparam, zparam in zip(wparameters, bparameters):
    update.append((wparam, wparam + tr_rate*(pos_associations - neg_associations)))
    update.append((zparam, zparam + tr_rate*(x - vis))
```

Answer (score 0):

`update += [(z, z + tr_rate*(x - vis))]`
does this work?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10998255)

Comment: @vape oh, actually I am suggesting an answer, but I'm not sure if it works, should I do it as comments?